# How can I make these three MYSQL queries into one?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this query:

```
SELECT da_clubs_categories.name AS cat_name,
    da_clubs_categories.id AS cat_id,
    da_deals.id,
    da_brands.id AS brand_id,
    da_brands.name AS brand_name
    FROM da_clubs_categories, da_deals, da_brands
    WHERE da_clubs_categories.fk_club_id = da_brands.fk_club_id
    AND da_brands.fk_club_id = 6
    AND da_deals.fk_brand_id = da_brands.id
    AND FIND_IN_SET(da_clubs_categories.id, da_deals.categories) > 0
    AND da_brands.active = 1
    AND da_deals.active = 1
    AND da_deals.date_start <= CURRENT_DATE()
    AND CURRENT_DATE() <= da_deals.date_end
    ORDER BY da_clubs_categories.name ASC, da_deals.date_start DESC
```

Results:

```
+--------------+--------+----+----------+------------+
| cat_name     | cat_id | id | brand_id | brand_name |
+--------------+--------+----+----------+------------+
| Deporte      |     19 | 22 |       57 | Marca1     |
| Deporte      |     19 | 23 |       57 | Marca1     |
| Deporte      |     19 | 24 |       57 | Marca1     |
| Deporte      |     19 | 25 |       57 | Marca1     |
| Deporte      |     19 | 26 |       57 | Marca1     |
| Deporte      |     19 | 27 |       57 | Marca1     |
| Deporte      |     19 | 28 |       57 | Marca1     |
| Deporte      |     19 | 29 |       57 | Marca1     |
| Gastronomía  |     20 | 22 |       57 | Marca1     |
| Salud        |     21 | 22 |       57 | Marca1     |
+--------------+--------+----+----------+------------+
```

Later on, another query:

```
SELECT value AS 'like'
FROM da_logs
WHERE fk_deal_id = 22
AND type = 'deal_like'
```

RESULT:

```
+------+
| like |
+------+
| ::1  |
+------+
```

Later on, another query:

```
SELECT value AS 'rating'
FROM da_logs
WHERE fk_deal_id = 22
AND type = 'deal_rating'
```

RESULT:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| rating                                                     |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| a:2:{s:7:"user_ip";s:3:"::1";s:12:"rating_value";s:1:"3";} |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I had to do that using loops in PHP but I want to make just one single query, specifically tableA with two additional columns (I did 2 additional queries) as you could see.

If like or rating is not found for a specific DEAL then set it to ''.

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` to join with these tables. If there's no match, `LEFT JOIN` will return `NULL` for the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to join with the `da_logs` table twice, once for each `type` you want to match.

```
SELECT da_clubs_categories.name AS cat_name,
    da_clubs_categories.id AS cat_id,
    da_deals.id,
    da_brands.id AS brand_id,
    da_brands.name AS brand_name,
    IFNULL(l1.value, '') AS like,
    IFNULL(l2.value, '') AS rating
    FROM da_clubs_categories
    INNER JOIN da_brands ON da_clubs_categories.fk_club_id = da_brands.fk_club_id
    INNER JOIN da_deals ON da_deals.fk_brand_id = da_brands.id
        AND FIND_IN_SET(da_clubs_categories.id, da_deals.categories) > 0
    LEFT JOIN da_logs AS l1 ON l1.fk_deal_id = da_deals.id AND l1.type = 'deal_like'
    LEFT JOIN da_logs AS l2 ON l2.fk_deal_id = da_deals.id AND l2.type = 'deal_rating'
    WHERE da_brands.fk_club_id = 6
    AND da_brands.active = 1
    AND da_deals.active = 1
    AND da_deals.date_start <= CURRENT_DATE()
    AND CURRENT_DATE() <= da_deals.date_end
    ORDER BY da_clubs_categories.name ASC, da_deals.date_start DESC
```